# TV connected via thunderbolt 3 port not working

Tags: display, bootcamp, hdmi

I’m not sure if this is the appropriate place to post this question because it concerns Apple hardware but windows software.

I have a thunderbolt 3 to hdmi cable connecting my iMac 5K retina (2017) to my 4K TV. On Mac OS it works immediately and looks great. No issues.

I have a boot camp partition running windows 10 and the TV claims no signal.

If I am in the wrong area could you please help me understand a more appropriate place to post this question? Thanks.

Comment: Not that  is helps, but display adaptors working with macOS (OS X) and failing with Boot Camp (Windows) is not an unusable occurrence.

Comment: Do you mean unusual? I thought boot camp handles all of the drivers and firmware requirements in Apple hardware. So this would include the functionality of the port right?

Comment: I have used a 2006 iMac, 2007 iMac, 2011 iMac, 2013 iMac and 2018 mac mini with adaptors to a HDTV. All worked with macOS (OS X), but not Boot Camp (Windows). I am not saying there is not a adaptor that would work. However, my experience has been the adaptors do not.